# Retain the columns whose fulfils the specific condition with respect to columns

Tags: shell-script

[image]

**ExAC_SAS=0.8184** and **AF=0.5**  I want to retain the columns whose ExAC_SAS >.9 and AF > .5 as these sub columns have random postion in the last column i.e column 8

Thank you,
I hope I am clear with my question

Comment: Please edit your question and put the relevant data in a code block so that we can copypaste and test. Screenshots are difficult in that respect :-)

Comment: Are you sure they have "random position"? In this tiny sample, they loop like they are in the same place.

Comment: @glennjackman yes they are in the random postion in 8 column seperated by semicolons. This samples has >100000 lines out of which i have just kept 2 line.

Comment: @Edward  <br/>  1  762273  rs31  G  A  2111.77  PASS   AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;CLNSIG=.;ExAC_ALL=0.8060;ExAC_AFR=0.4415;ExAC_AMR=0.8116;ExAC_EAS=0.9174;ExAC_FIN=0.9;ExAC_NFE=0.8384;ExAC_OTH=0.8896;ExAC_SAS=0.8184;SAS.sites.2015_08=.;avsnp150=rs3115849  GT:AD  0/1:84,85  <br/>  
1 76  rs145  C  T  136.77  PASS  AC=1;AN=2;AF=0.5;ExAC_ALL=0.0901;ExAC_AFR=0.1404;ExAC_AMR=0.0551;ExAC_EAS=0.0366;ExAC_FIN=0.0294;ExAC_NFE=0.0652;ExAC_OTH=0.0556;ExAC_SAS=0.1106  GT:AD  0/1:27,8